# decoding morse value to alphabet

Tags: c++

I am trying to decode the morse code to english. Basically I get string of line from the file
and line my show up like for example

```
** -* -  --** --- --- -- L* ***- * *-**  = -- *- *--* V** * *-- .--*
```

I have space between codes I should delimit the any other charater except upper isspace next
to morse code. I have a tree which contain morse and associated morse code, i have tested manually it return the letter. But problem is decoding part reading each morse code and passing to my conversion from morse to letters.
Please I am desperate for help. Any hint.

Comment: Please improve formatting and grammar...

Comment: This is impossible to answer currently, because it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: If you already know the tokens are space-delimited, what is the problem exactly? Also, which characters are supposed to be dots and which ones dashes? You now have `*` `-` `L` `V` `=` and `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an homework question, you should Tag it as @homework if so.

You should have a binary tree that maps the letters to nodes where one side symbols '*' and the other side symbols '-'.
Each node should have: LeftChild, RightChild, Letter.

To parse the text you should get each char and traverse the Morse code tree until you reach a space. When you reach a space you should get the Letter in the node you reached and start again from the root of the tree.

There should be also a char that represents the end of a word, is it 'L'?

If you give some more information, people will be able to help you...

Comment: My already tree contains code and associated alphabet. Well I was parsing it to vector before. Well basically read string from the file which morse code values, I am stuck read each morse value, when I read each morse value I pass the morse code to my tree and it returns the alphabet. Any example will boost my knowledge.